# Source to destination Key Field mapping in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have a elastic search index with source data coming in the following way:

```
        "_source": {
            "email": "smithamber@example.com",
            "time": "2022-09-08T13:52:50.347861",
            "message": "Pattern thank talk mention. Manage nearly tell beat. Difficult husband feel talk radio however.",
            "sIp": "192.168.11.156",
            "dIp": "80.254.211.60",
            "ts": "2022-09-08T13:52:50"
        }
```

Now I want a way to treat dynamically map `@timestamp` [destination key] field of ES doc to be `time` [source key]. For this i am using:

```
 "runtime_mappings": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ",
            "script": {
                "source": "if (doc[\"time\"].size() == 0) {return} else {return doc[\"time\"].value;}",
                "lang": "painless"
             }
            }
        }
```

However, this does not work. Is there a better way to map `source key` field to `destination key` field in elastic search. I am open to static mapping as well if we set once before creating the index for one kind of source data.

I am looking for correct syntax for mapping my field.

Edited:
When I add the query -

```
{     "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-5d",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see no hits.

```
{
"took": 20,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 0,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
}
}
```

However, same query on field `time` gets me all filtered docs.

```
{
"took": 27,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 10000,
        "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "topic-indexer-xxx",
            "_id": "c28sIYMB0xJUJru8c47O",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "email": "albertthompson@example.com",
                "time": "2022-09-07T15:25:33.672016",
                "message": "Candidate future staff ever former run. Like quality personal specific trouble cell money move. Available majority memory model thing TV wrong. Summer anyone light key.",
                "sIp": "192.168.103.75",
                "dIp": "191.27.68.163"
            }
        },
  ....
  }
```

For mapping I have also tried dynamic templates; but still no results on query for `@timestamp` field:

```
{
"dynamic_templates": [
  {
    "@timestamp": {
      "match":   "time",
      "mapping": {
        "type":       "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
        "copy_to":    "@timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

---

With @paulo's response, I just did a little fine tuning to resolve the issue; The below mapping (as set) works and then I can run range queries on the `@timestamp` field:

```
{
  "runtime": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "script": {
        "source": "if (doc['time'].size() != 0){ emit(doc['time'].value.toEpochMilli());}",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by its not working ? any error or unexpected results?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast: How do i query on `@timestamp` field now. Adding query and results observation.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I use the destination key field.

Comment: Can you share the one sample result of your query when you use the `time` field, you should see the `timestamp` field in the result

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast Added both results

Comment: I guess you forget to use the `emit` as mentioned https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html (When defining a Painless script to use with runtime fields, you must include the emit method to emit calculated values.)

Comment: Unfortunately emit is not helping. I think fundamentally I haven't seen any example of using dynamic mappings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247975/discussion-between-amit-es-enthusiast-and-ankita-mehta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

I feel you go mixed up in your painless script.
Please find below an example you should be able to reproduce on your side.

`Time` is already a date on my side. Elasticsearch was able to detect it automatically.

On another note, using runtime fields while very flexible, may lead to performance issue on the long run.

Maybe you should be looking into [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html).

## Solution

```json
POST /73684302/_doc
{
  "email": "smithamber@example.com",
  "time": "2022-09-08T13:52:50.347861",
  "message": "Pattern thank talk mention. Manage nearly tell beat. Difficult husband feel talk radio however.",
  "sIp": "192.168.11.156",
  "dIp": "80.254.211.60",
  "ts": "2022-09-08T13:52:50"
}

POST /73684302/_doc
{
  "email": "smithamber@example.com",
  "message": "Pattern thank talk mention. Manage nearly tell beat. Difficult husband feel talk radio however.",
  "sIp": "192.168.11.156",
  "dIp": "80.254.211.60",
  "ts": "2022-09-08T13:52:50"
}

GET /73684302/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        if (doc["time"].size() != 0){
          emit(doc["time"].value.toEpochMilli());
        }
        """,
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": false, 
  "fields": ["@timestamp"]
  
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo,
Something is off with the quote character syntax here. I have added screenshot in the Question.

Comment: This is working with a little bit of fine tuning. I made source true as i wanted all data in _search output.
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['time'].value.toEpochMilli());",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": true,
  "fields": ["@timestamp"]
}

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to demo the effect of the runtime fields without all the noise of the source, so I set on purpose the `_source: false`